# Single-user OAuth error with api v1.1

Tags: python, twitter

I'm having trouble authenticating with the Twitter api. I'm using the oauth2 module in Python to conduct a single user sign-in.

I've been using the following function to request follower ids:

```
import oauth2 as oauth

def oauth_req(url, key, secret, http_method="GET", post_body=None, http_headers=None):
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=key, secret=secret)
    token = oauth.Token(key=key, secret=secret)
    client = oauth.Client(consumer, token)
    resp, content = client.request(
        url,
        method=http_method,
    )
    return content
```

I'll then run it from a document call twitter_auth.py as per the below example:

```
ids = twitter_auth.oauth_req('https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/ids.json?cursor=-1&screen_name=marksandspencer', 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET')
```

It then just returns the following:
    '{"errors":[{"message":"Invalid or expired token","code":89}]}'

I can't seem to get it work, my application details are fine and not expired - so I'm assuming they might be invalid in some way - I just can't work out how.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing in a CONSUMER_KEY and a CONSUMER_SECRET but not a TOKEN_KEY and TOKEN_SECRET, so your token variable is using the same credentials as your consumer. The Access Token credentials need to be requested either via your code or manually on the Twitter website.